# ng build --prod removes subfolders. brakes page reload

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular 2.1 application with lazily loaded sub modules. The sub modules are in subfolders and require a URL segment to navigate (localhost:4200/sub-component). The navigation works fine when I run in the development mode (ng serve). In this mode the application is also bookmarkable, meaning that I can reload any page and it will render fine. When I build it for production (ng build --prod) and deploy, the navigation still works fine, but it is no longer bookmarkable: page reload causes 404 error, because the deployment package produced by CLI has no subfolders.

Comment: I found a workaround. I do not like it but I will post it so that others can use it if necessary. The navigation problem disappears if you use hash URL strategy: RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true})

Answer (score 0):

Your web server is attempting to handle the request at that URL. You need to configure your server to redirect those requests to the default URL and which will load your application. Once the application loads it will redirect the SPA to the desired client-rendered route.

The CLI dev server handles that for you by default.

Comment: Is there any documentation on how to do this?

Comment: More specifically, how can I do it if the Angular application is served by Node.js / Express.js?